# python3 how to install couchdb module on raspbian

Tags: python-3.x, couchdb-python

I have spent a couple of months developing an application that uses the python module for couchdb, and now I want to deploy it, I can't remember how I first installed it, I thought it was a simple:

```
sudo apt-get install couchdb-python
```

but I seem to have got that wrong, how can I get this now for python3 please?